# Como passar números para letras do alfabeto

Tags: javascript, array

Converte Números de `1 ao 26` para `A - Z` do Alfabeto. Tenho um diretorio com varios arquivos e queria fazer um "FOR" para, ... o nome(arquivo). Estou fazendo isso com os arquivos nomeados por números ordinais, mas gostaria de fazer isso com arquivos nomeados por letras.

```
<script>

    var dir = "video"; // acessa o diretório vídeos, onde estão os vídeos .3gp e suas thumnail .png
window.onload = function(){
    var alfabeto = "3";
for (i = 1; i <= alfabeto; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += "<a href='"+dir+"/"+i+".3gp' target='player'><img src='"+dir+"/"+i+".png' class='option'></a>";
    }
}
</script>
```

Bom pessoal espero ter me expressado o suficiente para que possamos juntos encontrar a solução, conto com ajuda de vocês. Agradeço, desde já.

Comment: E o que já fez para resolver seu problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim como toda linguagem, o `javascript` também pode trabalhar com valores numéricos de caracteres, claro que não tão bem quanto em C e C++.

Primeiramente, você precisa estar ciente de que os valores de 1 a 26 não podem virar letras, pois os valores das letras na `tabela ascii` começam em 65, então você deve somar 64 sempre que for converter seu numero para caractere.

```
>> var char_A = 1;
>> console.log(String.fromCharCode(char_A+64))
'A'
```

E a operação reversa fica.

```
>> var num_1 = 'A';
>> console.log(num_1.charCodeAt(0)-64)
1
```

O parâmetro passado em `charCodeAt`, representa a posição do caractere na string.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Brumazzi D.B

Agradeço pela sua atenção no que diz respeito a minha questão.

Feito! Deixo aqui o código para futura pesquisa por parte de outros  usuários.

```
<script>

    var dir = "video";
    window.onload = function(){
    alfabeto = 26
    for (i = 1; i <= alfabeto; i++) {
    var cod = (String.fromCharCode(i + 64));
    document.body.innerHTML += "<a href='"+dir+"/"+cod+".3gp' target='player'><img src='"+dir+"/"+cod+".png' boder='0'/></a>";
    }
}

</script>
```